# Arranging numbers into a grid using the Split Text extension and the Arrange dialog in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I want to create a grid of numbers for a calendar like layout like this:

[image: screenshot of inkscape 0.92]

**Steps to follow:**

1. Writing the numbers 1-9 separated by spaces in a text object.
2. Extensions > Text > Split Text..., select Split by Words.
3. Object > Arrange... set 3 rows by 3 columns, left-top aligned, Set spacing.

It works in Inkscape 0.92 but it fails in the latest 1.0.1 inkscape like this:
[image: screenshot of inkscape 1.0.1]

**Workaround**

Of course, do this in the older Inkscape and copy paste the arranged grid into the latest version.

**Question**

How to get this working in 1.0.1?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

If you want this to work in inkscape 1.0.1, instead of using auto-flowed text, that is created when you draw a text box by click dragging, just click once and start typing the text that you want to split later.

This is a known issue in Inkscape 1.0.1 and is listed here - [in the inkscape issue tracker](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/extensions/-/issues/257)

**Credit:**
Thanks a lot to Nathan L from #inkscape on IRC for helping with this!